# Chosen module/jquery plugin not accessible on mobile devices?

Tags: 7

I have installed the Chosen Module and was surprised to find out when viewing the page on an actual mobile device or on a desktop mobile device simulator that the Chosen menu is totally missing from the html markup and the menu items are not being displayed on the device.

Anyone know by any chance what I may be missing here? Is it possible the module only works for desktop or tablet devices?

Answer (score 1):

I just found on the Chosen jQuery [documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in the FAQ section towards the bottom they say that they have disabled the Chosen module for mobile devices by default as there are bugs with the Menu working properly on those devices. Here is a [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/1388) about the issue.